# ubuntu does not control fan speed on acer predator

Tags: ubuntu, fan

## The Problem

I would like the fans to automatically adjust speed based on appropriate internal temperatures. I have a dual-boot with Windows 10 and it works as expected under Windows. However, when I log in to Ubuntu, the fans are quiet for about 30 seconds and then spin up to what I'm guessing is about 70-80%.

## Diagnostics

I took the following steps:

1. `sensors-detect`
2. `service kmod start`
3. `sensors`
4. `pwmconfig`

The output of each of these commands can be found in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/j31WSccY).

## Conclusion

I don't know much about hardware/drivers/modules, so I'm a little out of my element. `pwmconfig` obviously isn't finding the fan(s), but I don't know why or what driver/module to look for to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not impossible that `pwmconfig` could not find a chip that does indeed control fan speed but I doubt it.  Based on the fact that you notice a speed change, there is either a problem with the fans, or they're controlled internally and can not be controlled by software.  Did you really test it thoroughly in Windows to see the thresholds for the fan speed to change and compare it with Linux?

Comment: On Windows, I could hear the fans speed up and slow down as I was doing things that were more/less cpu intensive (like mounting VirtualBox instances). There is also pre-installed software from the manufacturer that allows me to check a box to immediately turn the fans to 'max. speed', which I did check just to see. That's the reason I'm guessing the fans are at 70-80% on Ubuntu. They don't seem to be running as loud as they were when I checked that box on windows.

Comment: There is definitely no change on linux other than the fans boosting to a high speed after I'm logged in for 30 seconds. After that, they never waiver. Granted, I'm going by sound, but I've worked on multiple systems that had fans that adjusted based on temp. and I could hear noticeable changes in the fans on all of them based on load.

Comment: Did you compare it with the CPU temperature?  That's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the nvidia driver:

1. go into 'software & updates'
2. click on 'additional drivers' tab
3. choose the NVidia binary driver (proprietary)
4. click 'Apply Changes' (this took several minutes to apply)
5. reboot

It took several reboots before it worked, but I believe this was due to having an external monitor plugged in at the time. Once I unplugged the monitor and rebooted using just the laptop screen, I was able to then add the monitor while it was running and adjust display settings.

The fan is now operating as expected and corresponds to the cpu temperature.

Answer (score -2):

Hey There I Recently Created A Config(nbfc) File For Acer Predator Helios 300(RTX 2060) And This Working For Me Flawlessly
Hope It Will Also Work For You
https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/pull/1039/files#diff-50ddd4e9ba6abe03c49bc65914eb62a60b506a5ce12e46df5857e012a7584390

Comment: Why are you writing in "Title Case"? Also, this is a link only answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.